# Array of values ILIKE some value

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

Lets say I have an array of strings returned by some subquery. And I want to make sure that at least one of the elements is matching with string (for example: ILIKE "%alex%"). What should I do for that?
My code:

```
ANY(ARRAY["Alexander", "Michael", "John"]) ILIKE "%alex%"
```

is not working at all.
I need a solution which will return true in my case, because one of the elements(Alexander) is ILIKE "%alex%".

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: I'm using Postgresql

Comment: like this? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/228235/match-string-pattern-to-any-array-element/228262#228262 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to use `exists`:

```
where exists (select 1 from unnest(ARRAY['Alexander', 'Michael', 'John']) el where el ILIKE '%alex%')
```

Comment: Took me way too long to find this. In my case my column was the array so all the basic results on google didn't work. Thank you!